# How to return result celery to template django

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery

I've a task that have many querys in my database, 
some consults require time > 30s , and my server heroku , can't.

I would like to query and return to template.
my code

View:

`` `

```
class sales_filter(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
def get(self, request):
    data = {}
   task = searching.delay()

   return render(request, 'sales/sales_filter.html', data)
```

`` `

Task:

`` `

```
 @shared_task
 def searching():

  data['cod_parceiros'] = mapa.objects.values('cod_parceiro').distinct().\
        filter(mes_referencia__icontains=ano).order_by('cod_parceiro')

  return render(request, 'sales/sales_filter.html', data)
```

`` `

I tried this, but doesn't work.

Comment: The whole point of Celery is that it's for long-running tasks that can be completed after the page is returned to the user. So, no, you can't do this. Although if that simple lookup is taking longer than 30 seconds, I would urgently look into optimising your database.

Comment: IDEA: Just try to add JS for this page. You can make a 'while' on the background of your page when results will be ready JS will show it. But you probably you'll need a REST or something like separate view with serializer where you can get a result of this task from

Comment: @DanielRoseman, no, i'v some more than 10 querys... 
I just gave the example of a query. but thanks.

Comment: @trianglesis, thanks man... 
i'll try this.